# C++ Interface With Explicit Derived Methods

Tags: c++

I have a sample interface that delegates behavior to the implementing class:

```
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual void Do(IBase* base) = 0;
    virtual std::string name() = 0;
};
```

I then have 1..N classes that implement IBase:

```
class A : public IBase
{
public:
    virtual void Do(IBase* base);
    virtual std::string name() { return "A"; }
};

class B : public IBase
{
public:
    virtual void Do(IBase* base);
    virtual std::string name()  { return "B"; }
};
```

I then want the body of the Do() method to call free methods that are defined for everything that implements IBase:

```
void method(A* a, B* b)
{
    std::cout << a->name() << " " << b->name() << std::endl;
}

void method(B* b, A* a)
{
    method(b, a);
}
```

This doesn't compile because with this code because IBase cannot resolve to the derived type:

```
void Test::Run()
{
    IBase* a = new A();
    IBase* b = new B();

    b->Do(a);
}
```

How do I make this work, or something similar? The free methods implement all possible combinations, and it seems like there is a trick to get the IBase* to be acceptable in one of the overloads.

Secondly, how do you implement a interface scheme where each implementer has a shared method that takes an interface?  Perhaps this is better implemented with just free methods and removing the Do(IBase*) from the IBase interface.

Edit:
It works if (a) is declared to be type A. Whats the best way to make the code above work with the IBase?

```
void Test::Run()
{
    A* a = new A();
    IBase* b = new B();

    b->Do(a);
}
```

Literal code I am compiling:

```
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual void Do(IBase* base) = 0;
    virtual std::string name() = 0;
};

class A : public IBase
{
public:
    virtual void Do(IBase* base);
    virtual std::string name();
};

class B : public IBase
{
public:
    virtual void Do(IBase* base);
    virtual std::string name();
};

class Test
{
public:
    static void Run();
};

namespace
{
    void method(A* a, B* b)
    {
        std::cout << a->name() << " " << b->name() << std::endl;
    }

    void method(B* b, A* a)
    {
        method(b, a);
    }
}

void A::Do(IBase* base)
{
    method(this, base);
}

std::string A::name()
{
    return "A";
}

void B::Do(IBase* base)
{
    method(this, base);
}

std::string B::name() 
{
    return "B";
}

void Test::Run()
{
    IBase* a = new A();
    IBase* b = new B();

    b->Do(a);   
}
```

Visual Studio 2013:

Error   1   error C2665: '`anonymous-namespace'::method' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types 
Error   2   error C2665: '`anonymous-namespace'::method' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Comment: The search term you are looking for is ["double dispatch"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)

Comment: Your code compiles for me (adding #includes, main, and bodies for missing functions). Can you post an exact program which is not compiling, including the compiler messages?

Comment: @MattMcNabb Added exact code and error.

Comment: `method(this, &base)` is the wrong idea. , hopefully this was a typo for `method(this, base);` as you have later on

Comment: @MattMcNabb, Yep, typo. Still doesn't compile if fixed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand you correctly, you want A::Do to look like this:

```
void A::Do(IBase* other) {
   if other is A, then call:
      method(this,other) for arguments A,A
   else if other is B, then call
      method(this,other) for arguments A,B
   etc.
}
```

There are two answers to that. The best approach is usually to change the design. Make method a virtual function in IBase instead of a free function, and extract any functionality specific to A and B into yet another virtual function.

```
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual void Do(IBase* base) = 0;
    virtual std::string name() = 0;
    virtual void method(IBase* other);
    virtual void method2() = 0;
};

void IBase::method(IBase* other) {
    std::cout << name() << " " << other->method2() << std::endl;
}
```

The other option is to use type casting:

```
void A::Do(IBase* other) {
   if other is A, then call:
      method(this,dynamic_cast<A*>(other)))
   else if other is B, then call
      method(this,dynamic_cast<B*>(other))
   etc.
}
```

This approach usually does not scale well, is hard to maintain and error-prone.